# nodejs always error width Cannot read property data of undefined

Tags: node.js

my nodejs app always input this error:Cannot read property data of undefined, not only get data from java service ,but also query the db ,so please give me some advices,thanks;

Comment: If you're coming from Java, this is Node's version of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

At some point of your code you are accessing to property `.data` of a variable that has not been initialized. If this is happening while accesing a DB, make sure the query is right and you're receiving a valid response.